# mesh intersects itself during animation

Tags: animation, mesh, intersection

I'm new to animating cloth, and I have a small, probably basic question.

I have these really baggy pants, and the mesh is intersecting at the back of the knee during animation.

Adding more geometry there doesn't help the deformation. Could this be fixed with cloth physics or any other hacks? (currently it is just weight painted to a rig.)

[image]